# Flutter: Type 'UIApplication' has no member 'openSettingsURLString'

Tags: xcode, flutter

I am attempting to get the geolocator 2.1.0 plugin to work with my ios xcode project and get the following 2 erros after I run pod install

Type 'UIApplication' has no member 'openSettingsURLString'
and
'OpenExternalURLOptionsKey' is not a member type of 'UIApplication'

Steps taken.

1. I open a new Flutter project(Error occurs with or without 'Swift Support' checked) -get the default app.
2. Update my pubspec.yaml file with only - [geolocator](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/geolocator#-readme-tab-): ^2.1.0
3. Run 'flutter pacakges get' and 'pod install'.  All libraries show in AndroidStudio & XCode 9.2.

Hopefully I am missing something something simple.  Thanks for the help in advanced.

Podfile looks like this

(I have updated the file with ' config.build_settings['SWIFT_VERSION'] = '4.1'').

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '9.0'

# CocoaPods analytics sends network stats synchronously affecting flutter build latency.
ENV['COCOAPODS_DISABLE_STATS'] = 'true'

def parse_KV_file(file, separator='=')
  file_abs_path = File.expand_path(file)
  if !File.exists? file_abs_path
    return [];
  end
  pods_ary = []
  skip_line_start_symbols = ["#", "/"]
  File.foreach(file_abs_path) { |line|
      next if skip_line_start_symbols.any? { |symbol| line =~ /^\s*#{symbol}/ }
      plugin = line.split(pattern=separator)
      if plugin.length == 2
        podname = plugin[0].strip()
        path = plugin[1].strip()
        podpath = File.expand_path("#{path}", file_abs_path)
        pods_ary.push({:name => podname, :path => podpath});
      else
        puts "Invalid plugin specification: #{line}"
      end
  }
  return pods_ary
end

target 'Runner' do
  # Prepare symlinks folder. We use symlinks to avoid having Podfile.lock
  # referring to absolute paths on developers' machines.
  system('rm -rf .symlinks')
  system('mkdir -p .symlinks/plugins')

  # Flutter Pods
  generated_xcode_build_settings = parse_KV_file('./Flutter/Generated.xcconfig')
  if generated_xcode_build_settings.empty?
    puts "Generated.xcconfig must exist. If you're running pod install manually, make sure flutter packages get is executed first."
  end
  generated_xcode_build_settings.map { |p|
    if p[:name] == 'FLUTTER_FRAMEWORK_DIR'
      symlink = File.join('.symlinks', 'flutter')
      File.symlink(File.dirname(p[:path]), symlink)
      pod 'Flutter', :path => File.join(symlink, File.basename(p[:path]))
    end
  }

  # Plugin Pods
  plugin_pods = parse_KV_file('../.flutter-plugins')
  plugin_pods.map { |p|
    symlink = File.join('.symlinks', 'plugins', p[:name])
    File.symlink(p[:path], symlink)
    pod p[:name], :path => File.join(symlink, 'ios')
  }
end

post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings['ENABLE_BITCODE'] = 'NO'
      config.build_settings['SWIFT_VERSION'] = '4.1'
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add `use_frameworks!` in target Runner in your `(YOUR_PROJECT)/ios/Podfile`.

```
target 'Runner' do
  use_frameworks!  # required by Geolocator

  # Prepare symlinks folder. We use symlinks to avoid having Podfile.lock
  # referring to absolute paths on developers' machines.
  system('rm -rf .symlinks')
  system('mkdir -p .symlinks/plugins')
```

Older versions of the geolocator, such as `^1.6.3`, requires `SWIFT_VERSION` set to `4.0` or `4.1`.

But the `geolocator` version `2.1.0`, uses `permission_handler` version `2.1.1`, which requires `SWIFT_VERSION` `4.2`.

```
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings['SWIFT_VERSION'] = '4.2'  # required by Geolocator
      config.build_settings['ENABLE_BITCODE'] = 'NO'
    end
  end
end
```

I was able to successfully build and use `geolocator` version `2.1.0` in my app, using flutter `0.11.9` and Xcode `10.1`.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  Now I get "geolocator/geolocator-Swift.h" file not found" ?

Comment: It appears to be an issue with the fact that Libraary was written in Swift and the project is based in Obj-c ?  Will keep looking.

Comment: but are you combining the `use_frameworks` with `SWIFT_VERSION` 4.1?

Comment: Yes, the pod file now has both changes. Which, created the new issue mentioned in the comment above.

Comment: thanks again for the help.  So I need to update to XCode 10+ to get Swift 4.2.  Also did you create your Flutter project with or without the "Support for Swift" checked ? (At the initial creation of the Flutter project.)

Comment: No, didn't create the project with with the `-i` option - I used the default. I actually tried that with my existing app (upgraded geolocator), but as per your comment I just created a new project from scratch using default values and it built OK after I made the changes above.