# Not able to run flutter app on iOS Simulator

Tags: dart, flutter, dart-pub, flutter-dependencies

I am not able to run my flutter app on iOS Simulator. It is giving me this error :

Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone XR in debug mode...
Starting Xcode build...
Xcode build done.                                            7.9s
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
    ** BUILD FAILED **

Xcode's output:
↳
    === BUILD TARGET url_launcher OF PROJECT Pods WITH CONFIGURATION Debug ===
    /Users/snehal/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/simple_permissions-0.1.9/ios/Classes/SwiftSimplePermissionsPlugin.swift:51:38: error: 'UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString' has been renamed to 'UIApplication.openSettingsURLString'
                if let url = URL(string: UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString) {
                                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                                         UIApplication.openSettingsURLString
    UIKit.UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString:3:12: note: 'UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString' was obsoleted in Swift 4.2
    public let UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString: String
               ^

Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone XR.

Please Help. Thanks in advance :)

I want to run my app on iOS Simulator.

Comment: Does running "flutter devices" shows your Simulator in list? Also, "flutter doctor" shows any issue?

Comment: see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/53453243/796963

Comment: @Ganpat yeah it's showing the flutter devices as android emulator and iOS simulator too. And there are no issues when I am running a flutter doctor.

Comment: @Feu tried this also but not working :(

Comment: what swift_version did you use and what Xcode version are you using?

Comment: @Feu Scode version 10.1 and swift version 4.2

Comment: please check https://stackoverflow.com/a/54671608/4479395. it worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

if you have no luck then try to open with Xcode **(Build and Run Enjoy)**:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Open POD file in ios folder. Search 'SWIFT_VERSION' and change it to 4.2 ...like this

```
config.build_settings['SWIFT_VERSION'] = '4.2'
```

then do `flutter run`

Answer (score 1):

1. Open the project as @Nazmul Hasan has indicated with xcode.
2. Build the project.
3. Run the project.
4. Error will be shown
   [as follows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UwlOc.png)
5. click fix

Answer (score 0):

Did you check flutter channel ?

Firstly, you should check after run ***flutter channel*** command in terminal.

then , you should change flutter channel as master with 
***flutter channel master***  command.

Finally, restart IOS Simulator and run flutter in your application.

I hope that will be useful.

Answer (score 0):

hello my case is add dependencie wrong path haha. not about upgrade anything

please check dependencie if you try fix same on top comment then can't fix your problem.

in my case wrong path of asset , image , font of my project.

Answer (score -1):

Xcode installation is incomplete; a full installation is necessary for iOS and macOS development.
Download at: https://developer.apple.com/xcode/download/
Or install Xcode via the App Store.
Once installed, run:

```
    sudo xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    sudo xcodebuild -runFirstLaunch
```